# Downloading all full-text articles in PMC and PubMed databases

Tags: api, download, ncbi, pubmed

According to one of the answered questions by NCBI Help Desk , we cannot "bulk-download" **PubMed Central**. However, can I use "NCBI E-utilities" to download **all** full-text papers in PMC database using **Efetch** or at least find all corresponding PMCids using **Esearch** in Entrez Programming Utilities? If yes, then how? If E-utilities cannot be used, is there any other way to download all full-text articles?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, before you go downloading files in bulk, I highly recommend you read the [E-utilities usage guidelines](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/#_chapter2_Usage_Guidelines_and_Requiremen_).

If you want full-text articles, you're going to want to limit your search to open access files. Furthermore, I suggest also restricting your search to Medline articles if you want articles that are any good. Then you can do the search.

Using Biopython, this gives us :

```
search_query = 'medline[sb] AND "open access"[filter]'

# getting search results for the query
search_results = Entrez.read(Entrez.esearch(db="pmc", term=search_query, retmax=10, usehistory="y"))
```

You can use the search function on the [PMC website](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc) and it will display the generated query that you can copy/paste into your code.
Now that you've done the search, you can actually download the files :

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pmc", rettype="full", retmode="xml", retstart=0, retmax=int(search_results["Count"]), webenv=search_results["WebEnv"], query_key=search_results["QueryKey"])
```

- You might want to download in batches by changing `retstart` and `retmax` by variables in a loop in order to avoid flooding the servers.
- If `handle` contains only one file, `handle.read()` contains the whole XML file as a string. If it contains more, the articles are contained in `<article></article>` nodes.
- The full text is only available in XML, and the default parser available in pubmed doesn't handle XML namespaces, so you're going to be on your own with [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (or an other parser) to parse your XML.
- Here, the articles are found thanks to the internal history of E-utilities, which is accessed with the `webenv` argument and enabled thanks to the `usehistory="y"` argument in `Entrez.read()`

A few tips about XML parsing with ElementTree : You can't delete a grandchild node, so you're probably going to want to delete some nodes recursively. `node.text` returns the text in `node`, but only up to the first child, so you'll need to do something along the lines of `"".join(node.itertext())` if you want to get all the text in a given node.

Answer (score 0):

> According to one of the answered questions by NCBI Help Desk , we cannot "bulk-download" PubMed Central.

https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/medline.html + https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/openftlist/ will download a good portion of it (I don't know the percentage). It will indeed miss the PMC full-texts articles whose license doesn't allow redistribution as explained on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/openftlist/.